# True random color for div on demand

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, styles

I'm trying to use a random color for a `<div>` whenever the page loads, or on demand on refresh but it does not work. My code:

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        document.onload=function(){
            var red = Math.floor((Math.random()*256)+0);
            var blue = Math.floor((Math.random()*256)+0);
            var green = Math.floor((Math.random()*256)+0);
            var coloredDiv =  document.createElement("div");

            document.getElementById("coloredDiv");
            coloredDiv.style["background-color"] = 'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+')';
        }//]]>  
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="coloredDiv">A div that changes color randomly??!?!?!?!</div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript: location.reload(true);">Go again!</a>
</body>
```

Comment: and what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `background-color` using either of the below options:

**Option 1:**

```
window.onload=function(){
    var red = Math.floor((Math.random()*256)+0);
    var blue = Math.floor((Math.random()*256)+0);
    var green = Math.floor((Math.random()*256)+0);
    var coloredDiv =document.getElementById("coloredDiv");
    coloredDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+')';
}
```

---

**Option 2:**

```
coloredDiv.style["backgroundColor"] = 'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+')';
```

The key thing to note is that whenever we set value using JS for a CSS property which haa  hyphen in it (like `background-color`), the hyphen(s) should be removed and the first letter of the second and subsequent words should be capitalized.

Comment: I retract my answer. Switching to `window` instead of `document` will probably help. I had this same idea but got stuck on jsFiddle trying to double-check it. Is it possible jsFiddle doesn't call `window.onload`?

Comment: @shennan Under Frameworks and Extensions section on the left bar choose any option other than the "onLoad" and window.onload will work.